# What is the structure of "We aim to provide access to the largest team of detail specialists in the region"?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

In this sentence :

> We aim to provide access to the largest team of detail specialists in the region.

I see three verbs in it.
Could someone explain its structure to me?

Comment: There are only two verbs: *aim* and *provide.* Can you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Comment: thank your comment. 
"access to", What is its role in the sentence?
​

Comment: "Access" is a noun, the object of *provide.*

Answer (score 1):

In

> We aim to provide access to the largest team ...

the **infinitive** *to provide* is the complement of the verb *aim*; the noun *access* is the direct object of *to provide*; and *the largest team* is the indirect object of *to provide*.

As @alphabet said,  there are only two verbs, *aim* and *provide*.